# Scala chat application, blocking issue

Tags: java, multithreading, scala, sockets, blocking

I'm writing a chat application in Scala, the problem is with the clients, the client reads from StdIn (which blocks) before sending the data to the echo server, so if multiple clients are connected then they don't receive data from the server until reading from StdIn has completed. I'm thinking that local IO, i.e reading from StdIn and reading/writing to the socket should be on separate threads but I can't think of a way to do this, below is the Client singleton code:

```
import java.net._
import scala.io._
import java.io._
import java.security._

object Client {

  var msgAcc = ""

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val conn = new ClientConnection(InetAddress.getByName(args(0)), args(1).toInt)
    val server = conn.connect()
    println("Enter a username")
    val user = new User(StdIn.readLine())
    println("Welcome to the chat " + user.username)
    sys.addShutdownHook(this.shutdown(conn, server))
    while (true) {
    val txMsg = StdIn.readLine()//should handle with another thread?
    if (txMsg != null) {
      conn.sendMsg(server, user, txMsg)
      val rxMsg = conn.getMsg(server)
      val parser = new JsonParser(rxMsg)
      val formattedMsg = parser.formatMsg(parser.toJson()) 
      println(formattedMsg)
      msgAcc = msgAcc + formattedMsg + "\n"
      }
    }
  }

  def shutdown(conn: ClientConnection, server: Socket): Unit = {
    conn.close(server)
    val fileWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("history.txt"), true))
    fileWriter.write(msgAcc) 
    fileWriter.close()
    println("Leaving chat, thanks for using")
  }

}
```

below is the ClientConnection class:

```
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
import javax.net.SocketFactory
import java.net.Socket
import java.net.InetAddress
import java.net.InetSocketAddress
import java.security._
import java.io._
import scala.io._
import java.util.GregorianCalendar
import java.util.Calendar
import java.util.Date
import com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider
import scala.util.parsing.json._

class ClientConnection(host: InetAddress, port: Int) {

  def connect(): Socket = {
    Security.addProvider(new Provider())
    val sslFactory = SSLSocketFactory.getDefault()
    val sslSocket = sslFactory.createSocket(host, port).asInstanceOf[SSLSocket]
    sslSocket
   }

  def getMsg(server: Socket): String = new BufferedSource(server.getInputStream()).getLines().next()

  def sendMsg(server: Socket, user: User, msg: String): Unit = {
    val out = new PrintStream(server.getOutputStream())
    out.println(this.toMinifiedJson(user.username, msg))
    out.flush()
  }  

  private def toMinifiedJson(user: String, msg: String): String = {
    s"""{"time":"${this.getTime()}","username":"$user","msg":"$msg"}"""
  }

  private def getTime(): String = {
    val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
    cal.setTime(new Date())
    "(" + cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" + cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":" + cal.get(Calendar.SECOND) + ")"
  }

  def close(server: Socket): Unit = server.close()
}
```

This is the Client singleton using a Thread to read from standard input:

```
import java.net._
import scala.io._
import java.io._
import java.security._
import java.util.NoSuchElementException

object Client {

  var msgAcc = ""

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val conn = new ClientConnection(InetAddress.getByName(args(0)), args(1).toInt)
    val server = conn.connect()
    println("Enter a username")
    val user = new User(StdIn.readLine())
    println("Welcome to the chat " + user.username)
    sys.addShutdownHook(this.shutdown(conn, server))
    new Thread(conn).start()
    while (true) {
    val tx = conn.tx
    if (tx != null) {
      conn.sendMsg(server, user, tx)
      val rxMsg = conn.getMsg(server)
      val parser = new JsonParser(rxMsg)
      val formattedMsg = parser.formatMsg(parser.toJson()) 
      println(formattedMsg)
      msgAcc = msgAcc + formattedMsg + "\n" 
      }
    }
  }

  def shutdown(conn: ClientConnection, server: Socket): Unit = {
    conn.close(server)
    val fileWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("history.txt"), true))
    fileWriter.write(msgAcc) 
    fileWriter.close()
```

This is the ClientConnection class extending Runnable:

```
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
import javax.net.SocketFactory
import java.net.Socket
import java.net.InetAddress
import java.net.InetSocketAddress
import java.security._
import java.io._
import scala.io._
import java.util.GregorianCalendar
import java.util.Calendar
import java.util.Date
import com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider
import scala.util.parsing.json._

class ClientConnection(host: InetAddress, port: Int) extends Runnable {

  var tx: String = null

  override def run(): Unit = {
     tx = StdIn.readLine()
  }

  def connect(): Socket = {
    Security.addProvider(new Provider())
    val sslFactory = SSLSocketFactory.getDefault()
    val sslSocket = sslFactory.createSocket(host, port).asInstanceOf[SSLSocket]
    sslSocket
   }

  def getMsg(server: Socket): String = new BufferedSource(server.getInputStream()).getLines().next()

  def sendMsg(server: Socket, user: User, msg: String): Unit = {
    val out = new PrintStream(server.getOutputStream())
    out.println(this.toMinifiedJson(user.username, msg))
    out.flush()
  }  

  private def toMinifiedJson(user: String, msg: String): String = {
    s"""{"time":"${this.getTime()}","username":"$user","msg":"$msg"}"""
  }

  private def getTime(): String = {
    val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
    cal.setTime(new Date())
    "(" + cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" + cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":" + cal.get(Calendar.SECOND) + ")"
  }

  def close(server: Socket): Unit = server.close()
}
```

Comment: So what have you tried so far?  Do you know anything about multi-threading in Java?

Comment: I've tried having the ClientConnection class extend Runnable (in scala you extend instead of implement) and have the run() method perform the StdIn.readLine() and have the result stored in a class variable which I then accessed from the Client singleton, however this caused looping of the data being sent from the client to the server and back. I know a little about multithreading, the server uses a new thread each time a new client connects so that the socket listening for new connections (which blocks) and the socket IO are separate.

Comment: I think I know what you did wrong, from that description, but you should post the code where you did that so I can be sure.  If I understand you, you basically just updated what the StdIn input was in the other thread, but you repeatedly sent it in your main thread, whether or not it was changed?

Comment: Yes that's correct, I have edited the post to include how I tried to solve the problem. Of course the infinite looping is caused by the fact that the tx variable in the ClientConnection class is never null after it's first read from standard input

Comment: @user2069328 May I ask you a question? Why do you create scala application if 90% of your code is using java imports?

Comment: scala code is less verbose, also I use java where I can't find sufficient scala alternatives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you've successfully moved the reading of the input to the `Runnable`, so it will run on another `Thread`, but now when we look at the logic on your main thread, we see that it will always send the message if it's not `null`.  There are a few issues to this:

- You're not looping in the `run` method, so you're only going to receive a single message, and then your `run` method terminates - you want to wrap this in a `while(true)` or `while(<some boolean indicating you're not done>)` so you keep updating it.
- You still are printing out the messages from the server only after sending one to the server.  You should decouple this so that sending a message to the server is done on the other thread entirely.

Something along the lines of this might solve it:

```
//This is your new run method in your Runnable
override def run(): Unit = {
    while(true) {
        tx = StdIn.readLine()
        conn.sendMsg(server, user, tx) //Note you'll need to pass those references in somehow
    }
}`
```

Then, in your main thread, just deal with getting messages and printing them out:

```
new Thread(conn).start()
while (true) {
    //note the lack of sending messages in here
    val rxMsg = conn.getMsg(server)
    val parser = new JsonParser(rxMsg)
    val formattedMsg = parser.formatMsg(parser.toJson()) 
    println(formattedMsg)
    msgAcc = msgAcc + formattedMsg + "\n" 
}
```

This way, the two behaviors are on different threads.

Comment: Thanks that solved that problem, now there's a problem with the way the server echos data back. It keeps a list of connected clients and instantiates a new Thread with that list. So upon the first connection that Thread only has a reference to that one client, upon the second connection a new Thread has a reference to both clients so the second client can send data to itself and the other client, but the first client can only send data to itself as the first Thread has a reference to a list with only the first client in it.

Comment: @user2069328 That sounds like it should be in a separate question